# UK Long term visitors visa

Tags: visas, uk, malaysian-citizens

I am malaysian which gives me automatic 6 months tourist visa.  But as I am renovating my house in UK,I need to be travelling regularly to UK to supervise the renovation work and see my daugther who is studying there.  Can I apply for long term visitors visa and be in UK for at least 8 months in a year?
Or do I only get to be in UK for a maximum of 6 month in 1 year?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum time you can spend in the UK with a long-term Standard Visitor visa is 6 months on each visit https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa There is no restriction on the number of times you can enter using this visa however you should avoid giving the impression of using a visit visa to effectively live in the UK (see Immigration Rules v4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) The typical rule of thumb is to spend at least the same amount of time outside the UK as within it.
If you try to use the visa-free entry route to make frequent/extended visits you will probably run into a problem with Immigration relatively quickly.